# Mentioning "under review" manuscripts in industrial resume

Tags: career-development, research

I am a final year PhD student in chemistry and am applying for industrial R & D jobs. The thing is, presently my number of research publications is low as two of my submitted  manuscripts are under review for a long time in good peer review journals.

My questions are

1. If I mention these manuscripts in a seperate "under review" section of my resume? Do the employers in research and developement sector of industrial sector consider under review manuscripts? In academia  they are not valued much.
2. I also have a github project regarding the use of data science in my field of chemistry, which is also yet to be published in a peer reviewed journal. Should I also add this project to my resume?

Comment: Yes, it would be a good idea to add the GitHub project link to your resume or online application forms.

Comment: Thank you.... should I make the github project public before applying for jobs? currently it is private

Comment: How many is low? I would also keep your resume down to one page, two at most, creating a new section would make that difficult. Don't think you need anything like an academic CV or to pad it with a long list of courses you taught, awards, every little talk or publication you gave, etc.

Comment: @Relaxed Currently I have only one first author publication and two second author publications.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't even create a separate section, just include these publications, properly marking them as “Under review” or “submitted for publication”.

It depends on the field, the country, or the maturity of the organisation of couse but employers in industry might not care that much about publications in general. Or they might simply be impressed that you have any, even in R&D, especially if you apply for a relatively junior position. The recruiter and hiring manager will also spend very little time reviewing your resume and will be looking for keywords so that's another reason to include any relevant publication (say you have worked with a particular process they want to implement in the lab, that's a lot more important than your work being published).

I have had managers (even good ones) who just didn't know much about academia and publications, how to interpret authorship, etc. Some managers in industry R&D are either coming from academia or are researchers who rose through the ranks but I have also seen managers from a completely different part of the business doing a stint in R&D (either en route to something else or as some dead-end or punishment).

Be prepared to sell yourself, the relevance of what you do, and explain a lot. Don't be shy and do not make too many assumptions.